# Exception in main thread when executing java jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest, pdfbox

I have a java jar file i got below error when executing in ubuntu terminal .

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument
    at com.example.pdfbox.pdfbox.main(pdfbox.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

and my code is like:

```
package com.example.pdfbox;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

public class pdfbox {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PDDocument pd;
    BufferedWriter wr;


    String kunde = args[0];
    String sted = args[1];
    String plassering = args[2];



    try {
        File input = new File("/home/processdrive/Desktop/SKI108RE.PDF");

         pd = PDDocument.load(input);// line number 41
         System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
         System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());

         PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pd.getDocumentCatalog();

         PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();

         form.getField("Kunde").setValue(kunde);
         form.getField("Sted").setValue(sted);
         form.getField("Plassering").setValue(plassering);


         pd.save("/home/processdrive/Desktop/CopyOfInvoice.pdf");
         PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
         stripper.setStartPage(1); 
         stripper.setEndPage(1); 

 } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("Error occured");
        } 
     }
}
```

The 41 line is

```
pd = PDDocument.load(input);
```

My calss path is like

```
<classpath><classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/processdrive/Desktop/pdfbox/pdfbox-1.8.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/processdrive/Desktop/pdfbox/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/processdrive/Desktop/pdfbox/fontbox-1.8.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Well how are you *trying* to make the pdfbox jar file available to your program? Do you have a Class-Path entry in your manifest?

Comment: have you added the required `jar` files to your classpath?

Comment: @sankrish see my class path

Comment: @JonSkeet jar file is exported from eclipse..

Comment: @Ela: Your classpath in Eclipse is irrelevant - you should look at the entries in the jar file. I don't know what Eclipse does about adding Class-Path manifest entries.

Comment: @JonSkeet see my jar file order and export

Comment: @Ela: again, that's in Eclipse. Crack open the jar file and look at what is in the manifest.

Comment: @JonSkeet like this `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.pdfbox.pdfbox
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2`

Comment: @codo it runs fine in eclipse without showing any error.

Comment: @Ela: Right, well that's the problem then - no Class-Path entries, as I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the answer depends on how you are going to create your runnable JAR file. As you are using eclipse, I assume you simply *exported* your project.

First ... When exporting, always select *Runnable JAR file* as the export type when having a - hmm - runnable program (with a main class), as this will create the manifest file with all appropriate entries. The most important entries are - by the way - the *Main-Class* and the *Class-Path* entry.

The export wizard has a handful of options with which you can control *what* and *how* is really exported. This will also have an effect on the manifest file, of course. Look at this screenshot:

[image]

You see the three options regarding library handling? Let me explain:

- Extract required libraries into generated JAR

The easiest option for small programs. This will create one JAR file containing all classes (and other resources) of your libraries. In fact, the content of all libraries is extracted and put into the exported JAR. This is called a *Fat JAR*.

- Package required libraries into generated JAR

This is some other form of a fat JAR. All your libraries are put *as is* into the generated JAR file. That is, your generated JAR contains your classes and resources and all library JAR files. Starting your own main class now doesn't work, as JARs in JARs cannot be read correctly. Therefore eclipse creates a Main-Class entry in the manifest file pointing to the class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader`. This main class knows how to load the contents of all packaged libraries, and it starts your own main class.

- Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to generated JAR

This is the - I would say - most professional option. This is preferrable for larger projects. The generated JAR file will now only contain your project's classes and resource. Additionally a sub-folder (next to your JAR) will be created that contains all your library JARS. The manifest file of your JAR now must contain a Class-Path entry that lists all those libraries. This is what Jon Skeet asked for in his comment. The export wizard will create this manifest entry correctly.

---

Regardless of what export option you select, you are then able to start your program with a simple

> java -jar your-jar-file

Comment: You're welcome. For your program, I suggest to use the first option. This is probably what you want. Later (much later) you will learn how to use build tools - such as Apache Maven - with which you also control the JAR creation including manifest configuration.

Comment: i got this warning warning pdf file not closed.

Comment: Another problem => another question. This is semantic problem with your program.

Answer (score 0):

this is Build path problem

Right click project-->click build path-->Configure Build Path-->Order and Export--> and check weather your library is checked if not do check your library.

and run your project

Comment: this could rather be single line comment or general answer . be specific

Comment: Thanks for your answer..my libraries are checked. When run in eclipse it works fine..

Comment: it is already fine in eclipse. My problem is in ubuntu terminal..i think u misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Check for proper jar version. following pdfbox.jar had PDFDocument defination,

```
[MAVEN] pdfbox-0.6.4.jar
[MAVEN] pdfbox-0.7.1.jar
[MAVEN] pdfbox-0.7.3.jar
```

the jar you are using dont have needed class definition.

Comment: When run in eclipse it works fine..same time run in terminal show error